# lag difference by id issue

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

I have a dataset like this

```
 ID     Date        Total  
 1      2002-03-12   4.98
 1      2003-06-06   5.49
 2      2005-10-10   2.62
 2      2010-04-07   2.02
 2      2012-04-03   2.40 
 2      2014-04-10   2.45
```

I am trying to calculate the difference between the Total(t+1) and Total(t) value by each ID.

The final expected dataset should be as follows

```
 ID     Date        Total    Delta
 1      2002-03-12   4.98    NA
 1      2003-06-06   5.49    0.51 = 5.49 - 4.98
 2      2005-10-10   2.62    NA
 2      2010-04-07   2.02    -0.6 = 2.02 - 2.62 
 2      2012-04-03   2.40    0.38 = 2.40 - 2.02
 2      2014-04-10   2.45    0.05 = 2.45 - 2.40
```

I tried this below

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Id, Date) %>%
   arrange(Id, Date) %>%
   mutate(
     Delta = (Total - lag(Total, 1))
   )
```

This is not working, I am seeing NAs in column Delta. Any suggestions or help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the Date from the group_by call. You essentially are telling R to calculate for each unique combination of ID and Date, since there is no repeats in the date, the lag call is churning up NA

Comment: @NotThatKindODr, that worked. Thanks.